# Version not incremented during transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

I have the following scenario:

1. transaction begin
2. person.getVersion() --> returns 0
3. person.setName("dirty");
4. session.save(person);
5. person.getVersion() --> returns 0
6. session.flush()
7. person.getVersion() --> returns 1
8. transaction commit

What could I do to get the updated version in step 4 without actually forcing a session flush or transaction commit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Very easy: Do

```
person.getVersion() + 1
```

Do you smile? But it is exactly this what hibernate is doing with the version property.

In the moment of the update into the database hibernate reloads the record from the database and compares the version value with the version value of the java object. If they are the same  then hibernate increments the version value by one and stores the new record into the database, if not it throws an exception. The idea is, if any other application modifies the record in the meantime, the modified values must not be overwritten and our application must reload the data and modify the new value.

Sure hibernate could modify the version value the first time when any values in the java object are modified. But then each time a value is modified hibernate has to check if the object is modified (the new value can be the same as the old value; in this case no update is necessary), and it has to mark if the version value already is incremented or not. Why doing this if you don't win anything?

By the way, hibernate does not update the database record in the moment of the save(), but in the moment of a flush() or commit(), because this allows to re-order the database statements for better performance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Johanna! Yes, I knew the theory behind the version and how Hibernate does it internally but I just don't know how could I actually get the new version(without the v+1 thing - which actually made me smile :) ) from inside the transaction. As I see it, I guess it's impossible.

Comment: in any case, this looks like a very reasonable explanation - I like the final part with why Hibernate doesn't do version increments inside the transaction. It made me understand Hibernate a little bit better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that!
You could use repositories to save your data and resign using a transaction. This depends on your context!

If you have several calls with write access to the database and want them to be rolled back when an error occurs, then you have to you @Transactional around the operations.

But a single save operation does not need a transaction around it, because the repositories operate transactional by design.